# remove header link from a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a company site using wordpress free theme storymag.I download this theme  from

http://newwpthemes.com/themedemo/?wptheme=StoryMag .

I integrated whole theme using my requirement,but in last when I try to remove default footer link. then my site is close and i saw a message in a page

"All the links in the footer should remain intact. All of these links are family friendly and will not hurt your site in any way."

when I try to remove a single word then my theme get close.My client doesn't want to show these links in footer.
In footer.php I found this line.

```
   <div id="credits"><strong>WordPress</strong></a> | Designed by: <a 
    href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/">Best SUV</a> | Thanks to <a 
      href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/lexus-suv/">Lexus SUV</a>, <a 
     href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/safest-suvs/">Safest SUVs</a> and <a 
            href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/nissan-suv/nissan-rogue/">
        Nissan Rogue</a></div><!-- #credits -->
```

If I make a single change in this line link then theme stop working.
what can i do?please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search engines will sill see the links if you use `display:none;`

Open your footer.php and add `<?php if(false) { ?>` above and `<?php } ?>` below the credit line.

So the code like

```
<?php if(false) { ?>
        <div id="credits">Powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org/"><strong>WordPress</strong></a> | Designed by: <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/">Best SUV</a> | Thanks to <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/lexus-suv/">Lexus SUV</a>, <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/safest-suvs/">Safest SUVs</a> and <a href="http://suv.reviewitonline.net/nissan-suv/nissan-rogue/">Nissan Rogue</a></div><!-- #credits -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The theme checks if the credit line is placed in the footer.php. Hence if you remove it you will get the error message. To remove the check changes are need in 3 files. Simpler way is, instead of removing the check, we just use if(false) condition to the credit line. if(false) condition always fails and hence doesn't add the credit line to the page(footer).

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you could do.

You could dive into the theme's source to find where it stops working if you don't have that credits line.

You could also use CSS to hide those links. This is a pretty dodgy approach, but it will do the trick:

```
#credits {
    display:none;
}
```